# Checking for empty int, almost there

Tags: java, recursion, user-input

in my towers of hanoi program I am trying to check if the user doesn't enter any input when prompted for 'minimum discs' and 'maximum discs'. I originally only had minimum discs and got it working, now I can't seem to get past checking for an empty input when prompted for 'maximum discs'

**How do I check for empty input on my maximum discs prompt? If the user doesn't enter anything it defaults to solving my puzzle for 3 discs.**

*I commented out what I was attempting to solve in my code*

code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class hanoi {
    static int moves = 0;
    static boolean displayMoves = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(" Enter the minimum number of Discs: ");
        Scanner minD = new Scanner(System.in);
      String height = minD.nextLine();
      System.out.println();
      char source = 'S', auxiliary = 'D', destination = 'A'; // 'Needles'

      System.out.print(" Enter the maximum number of Discs: ");
        Scanner maxD = new Scanner(System.in);
      int heightmx = maxD.nextInt();
      System.out.println();

//       int iMax = 3;
//       if (heightmx.isEmpty()) {   //If not empty
//          iMax = Integer.parseInt(heightmx);
//          hanoi(iMax, source, destination, auxiliary);
//       }  


      int iHeight = 3; // Default is 3 
      if (!height.trim().isEmpty()) { // If not empty
      iHeight = Integer.parseInt(height); // Use that value

      if (iHeight > heightmx){
         hanoi(iHeight, source, destination, auxiliary);
      }

        System.out.print("Press 'v' or 'V' for a list of moves: ");
        Scanner show = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c = show.next();
        displayMoves = c.equalsIgnoreCase("v");   
      }

      for (int i = iHeight; i <= heightmx; i++) {     
           hanoi(i,source, destination, auxiliary);
         System.out.println(" Total Moves : " + moves);                    
      }
    }

    static void hanoi(int height,char source, char destination, char auxiliary) {
        if (height >= 1) {
            hanoi(height - 1, source, auxiliary, destination);
            if (displayMoves) {
                System.out.println(" Move disc from needle " + source + " to "
                        + destination);
            }
            moves++;
            hanoi(height - 1, auxiliary, destination, source);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextInt` there will be no empty ints

```
int height = minD.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Line:

```
int heightmx = maxD.nextInt();
```

should be:

```
String heightmx = maxD.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope

```
if (heightmx.isEmpty()) {   //If not empty
```

is a typo, since you are checking for empty and not the other way around (like your comments suggests).

Also, use

```
maxD.nextLine();
```

instead of

```
maxD.nextInt();
```

Comment: thanks. Hey could You help me with this really quick, this just stopped working for me but i do not know why, in my code: if I have an input of say Enter the minimum number of Discs: 3 Enter the maximum number of Discs: 2 The output should only solve for the minimum number of discs, 3 discs in this case. Why is my code not working for this case now? I compare the two but now it won't work!

Comment: The program just stops after asking for my inputs if the min discs is greater than the max discs. I need it to solve for the inputted min discs if min discs > max discs

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code or printing the values of height and heightmx here and there?

Comment: Glad I could help! Return the favor by accepting the answer ;)